# Slow down download speed for background jobs?

Tags: android, download

I got a Service which downloads a file. This file can be up to 200Mb. When downloading this file, I cant do any other http requests because the connection is fully used. Can I limit the download speed so that some small background requests still can be send and received?

Answer (score -1):

Are your code which downloads file runs in suparate `Thread`?

Using `Service` does **not** mean your code will run in separate `Thread`. Actually all `Service` life-cycle methods like `onCreate()`, `onBind()` and others are called in **main** application thread. If you download something from network in main thread it could be a reason of blocking other requests. Anyway, all your code which works with network/databases/files should be executed in separate threads.

If you are using separate threads for network operations, when you could insert `Thread.sleep(10)` in your while cycle between each portion of data has readed from stream.

Comment: All downloads are running in Threads. Thread.sleep is not what I want to use because I won't be able to set the download speed e.g. to 200kb/s or 30kb/s.